# Select a value from drop down in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="default_input_control Dropdown_Options single">
  <div class="default_input_field items custom_dropdown dropdown_arrow input_dropdown not-full has-options focus input-active dropdown-active">
    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="10">option1</div>
    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="20">option2</div>
    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="30">option3</div>
    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="40">option4</div>
```

Currently i am using xpath to select drop down and click options. Please let me know any other way I can select the drop down and click option 'option2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not a case of **"Select-type dropdown"** where you could have used the help of **"Select class"** of **"org.openqa.selenium.support.ui"** package, I think you are better off using click on the dropdown and then selecting the relevant option. You can however use **"Action class"** of **"org.openqa.selenium.interactions"** package on the dropdown too, like this:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of dropdown"))).click().perform();
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of option in the dropdown"))).click().perform();
```

**Note:- You can use "id, css, etc." as locators too. I have just used xpath to show how it works.**

Comment: @Gurunathan: Glad that it worked.. Please mark it as an answer if this has helped you.. Cheers. :)